# How can I use Fortran compiler?

Tags: compiler, fortran

I'm new to Ubuntu and don't know anything about using the command line.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and describe what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 5):

If you have the code below in the text file `hello.f90`

```
Program Hello
Print *, "Hello World!"
End Program Hello
```

To compile the code, start the terminal and type:

```
gfortran -o hello hello.f90
```

To run the code, type

```
./hello
```

You need to have the compiler installed. If it is not installed type the following in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install gfortran
```

The `hello.f90` file should be created in your home folder, e.g. using

```
gedit hello.f90&
```